The name field of register page is auto filled with word "Idm" can not find out why it's happening
I am working on a project with a multi authentication and everything's working fine but on my user register form the name field is auto filled with "Idm" and I can not find why it's happening.
I have checked in the page source code of the register page, and I can not see it in there either but when I duplicate the same name textbox it appears in the first textbox and the second one becomes empty. When I make the first name textbox hidden it comes again in the second textbox, and when I change the textbox type to email then it shows "idm@gmail.com". The most shocking thing is my database is empty and I can't find where is it coming from. Only thing I know is that I have used these as test data few days ago. The same thing happens on my other projects as well even though I haven't used any test data on them before.
If anybody could throw some light on this would be greatly appreciated as I have been spending days on this issue.
